# Q'est-ce que ça veut dire "Il fait bouffer ses anglaises orange et se repasse un peu de rouge à lèvres violet"?

Tags: sens

Je suis en train de lire "Jeux de la Faim" et j'ai tombé sur la proposition suivante dans le chapitre 5 de la première partie:

> Il fait bouffer ses anglaises orange et se repasse un peu de rouge à
>   lèvres violet.

Je pense que je comprenne tous les mots, mais je manque le sens néanmoins.

**P.S.**
Le français n'est pas ma langue maternelle (et même pas la langue seconde :-)), alors veuillez me pardonner, si tous ça vous heurte les oreilles.

Comment: Je suis français, et je suis dans la même situation que toi: cette phrase n'a aucun sens. On dirait une mauvaise traduction.

Comment: Voilà la proposition original en anglais: "He gives his orange corkscrew locks a shake and applies a fresh coat of purple lipstick to his mouth". Est-ce que cette phrase a le sens maintenant?

Comment: Vous comprendrez mieux comment on peut faire "bouffer" ses cheveux en voyant les images de coiffure à l'anglaise : https://www.google.fr/search?q=coiffure+anglaise&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:fr:official&gbv=2&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=_2oUUsMX6JzRBdrrgPgK&ved=0CEEQsAQ&biw=1310&bih=718

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pour la deuxième partie de la phrase, je ne vois pas de raison de penser que le sens soit autre que le sens évident : il applique du rouge à lèvres (*lipstick*) de couleur violette. L'utilisation du verbe *repasser* exprime qu'il en avait déjà mis avant.

Par contre, « bouffer ses anglaises orange », je ne comprends pas sans contexte. Même avec le contexte, je n'aurais probablement pas compris.

Avec l'original anglais, je comprends. Les *anglaises*, ce sont des boucles de cheveux allongées ([*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/anglaise) II.C.3), les « *corkscrew locks* » de l'original. Je ne connaissais pas. De là, je devine que « faire bouffer » signifie donner du volume ([TLF II.A.1](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bouffer)) : il passe sa main dans ses cheveux pour les faire tenir plus loin de sa tête, pour augmenter le volume extérieur de sa chevelure.

L'adjectif *orange* provient du nom du fruit et est en général considéré comme invariable, ce qui explique les « anglaises orange » et non « anglaises oranges ». Il en est de même pour la plupart des adjectifs de couleur qui proviennent d'un objet : on dirait « des anglaises marron », « des anglaises kaki ». Cependant les objets suffisamment assimilés comme noms de couleurs deviennent variables : « des anglaises roses », « des anglaises pourpres ».

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour cette excellente réponse. Je comprend tous maintenant.

Comment: J'avoue avoir eu un doute au début mais le contexte de fin de phrase suffit pour comprendre de quelles « anglaises » il s'agit.